# Problem with Apache rewrite rules. I want to redirect .com traffic to .co.uk

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is my current `vhost.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /data/sites/mysite
    ServerName mysite.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.mysite.co.uk
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.co\.uk|^www\.mysite\.com  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.co\.uk|^mysite\.com  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)        http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R]
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But I cannot get it to work properly. `www.mysite.com` is showing the `mysite.co.uk` website but the .com domain is still showing in the browser. Also if I go to `www.mysite.com/myfiles` it cannot find the folder that works on `www.mysite.co.uk/myfiles`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the .com domain to redirect all requests to the co.uk

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://yoursite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```